# adding ngTable module, data content is empty

Tags: jhipster, ngtable

I integrated ng-table to my jhipster project, with

```
bower install ng-table
```

All is ok. I added to index.html the module, I added to the app.js as module dependency.
I test the school case at the official website, helping with some basic example found on internet.
But nothing to do, the content of the table is ALWAYS empty, even with hard coded data content. My simplest example :

```
<div class="table-responsive"> 
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
                    <tr ng-repeat="myvar in $data">
                        <td title="'Myvar'" >
                            {{myvar}}</td>
                            <td title="'tableParams'" >
                            {{tableParams}}</td>
                    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

In the controller :

```
console.log("test log1");
            var data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50} /*,*/];
            $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams(
                {

                },
                {
                     total: 0,   // length of data
                        counts: [], // hide page counts control
                    getData: function($defer,  params)
                    {
                        console.log("test log3");
                        data = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50} /*,*/];
                         $defer.resolve(data.content);
                    },
                    data: [{name: "Moroni", age: 50} /*,*/],
                    dataset: [{name: "Moroni", age: 50} /*,*/]
                }

            );
```

Logs display well : "test log3" is displayed ! But the 'tableParams' or 'mywar' are always empty.

Need your help :(.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: I tried again, seems to work now (with hard coded data array in getData). I replaced "data.content" by "data" only.